# How to assign 0 For Null variable values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a form which will load leave already availed values from mysql database. But if the value is nothing it shows nothing in the output. But i need to show 0 in the ($avail field)for the null value how to get that
what i have tried is

```
$sqls = "SELECT  (@days :=  a.days  + @days) AS availed_days,days from tblleaves a,(SELECT @days:=0) c where 
LeaveType = '$type' AND empid ='$eid' ORDER BY availed_days desc ";

$querys = $dbh -> prepare($sqls);
$querys->bindParam(':eid',$eid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$querys->execute();
$results=$querys->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($querys->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{  
    $avail=($result->availed_days);
    //$actual=($result->days);

 ?>

 <input value=" <?php  echo $avail?>" id="avail_days" name="avail_days"  type="text"  >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$avail = $result->availed_days ?? 0;
```

This is the so-called [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

If `$result->availed_days` is null it will use the zero.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, still i can't solve the issue

Comment: still the echo value field doesn't show anything

Comment: If one record is entered with value it shows the value perfectly.. without entering any records this issue occurs

Comment: Sorry, I cannot run your code, and see what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value contains integers besides the possible NULL value. Cast it to an integer.

```
<?php echo intval($avail); ?>
```

Or

```
<?php echo (int) $avail; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, still i can't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be when there is no data as it can't reach the code that initializes the $avail variable(You might wanna check your if condition).

As a workaround you can pre-assign `$avail=0` before the `if`.